# Why the whole Table is locking during a MYSQL TRANSCTION?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, innodb

## Session 1 :-

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($conn);


$sql = "UPDATE foldertable set folderName = 'john' where folderName =  'john cen' AND serverToken= 1234 ";
mysqli_query($conn ,  $sql);
echo (mysqli_error($conn)) ;
echo(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)) ;
sleep (5) ;
mysqli_commit($conn) ;
```

I used `sleep(5)` knowingly , Just its an alternative for intense   work assume ;

suppose I have to update lots of records which takes 5 second to complete .

Now suppose 5 clients hit the same type of transaction . What I Observe that my table is locked for 25 minutes now .

### What I wanted

The insert query to Run without any hesitation .

```
INSERT INTO foldertable (serverToken , folderName ) VALUES (9874586 , poof)
```

The `foldertable` has 2 columns `serverToken` and `folderName`
The has been index as `serverToken`

```
--------------------------------
serverToken  | folderName
--------------------------------
1234         | ABC
--------------------------------
1234         | DEF
--------------------------------
1234         | GHI
--------------------------------
1234         | JKL
--------------------------------
4567         | ABC
--------------------------------
4567         | JHR
--------------------------------
4567         | COF
--------------------------------
4567         | JKL
--------------------------------
```

I don't want user `4567` to wait untill the user `1234` perform its updating in `foldertable` neither
the new insert of `serverToken` have to wait if the `serverToken` is not 1234 .

Comment: How is it different from the other question?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but are you sure you wanted to post two different questions? They look really similar. Please note that Stack Overflow is not a help desk. This question might get an answer today, in a year, or even never. Please visit [help] to learn more about Stack Overflow.

Comment: sorry For u r such a time waste I am deleting previous question . But I will be grateful if u will kindly answer it . Ones again sorry

Comment: No, please edit the old question instead. Deleteing questions is bad and it will lead to you getting question banned. Don't repost question in the future. Edit them instead. I linked them together right now